# Special divisors on smooth plane curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth, plane projective curve of degree $6$ and genus $10$ (over complex numbers).

**Question :** Is it possible that there exists a special divisor $\Delta$ of degree $10$    on $X$ such that it has exactly $5$ independent  sections?

**Observations :** $(1)$ From Clifford's Theorem, we have $h^0(\mathcal O_X(\Delta)) -1 =4 \leq \frac {\text{deg}(\Delta)}{2}=5$ and therefore it says this can happen.

$(2)$ If the curve $X$ is general, then from Theorem-$A$ of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06579.pdf), we have this is not possible.(Please correct me if I am wrong). This is also true from Brill-Noether theorem for general curves.

Can we say anything more in this situation when the curve $X$ is not necessarily general and if we know what $\Delta^2, K_X$ are?

Any insight from anyone is welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a divisor cannot exist. Let $H$ be the divisor of a line. By the base-point free pencil trick, we have an exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow H^0(\Delta -H)\rightarrow H^0(\Delta)^2\rightarrow H^0(\Delta +H)\,;$$since $\deg (\Delta +H)=16$, we have $h^0(\Delta +H)\leq 8$, hence $h^0(\Delta -H)\geq 2$.
Then $D:=\Delta -H$ is a $g^1_4$, thus base-point free since $X$ is not trigonal. Now applying again  the base-point free pencil trick, we get
an exact sequence
$$ 0\rightarrow H^0(H-D)\rightarrow H^0(H)^2\rightarrow H^0(\Delta )$$
which tells us $h^0(H-D)>0$. Thus $D\equiv H-p-q$, for some points $p,q$ in $X$; but this implies $h^0(D)=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: From $\text{deg}(\Delta+H) =16$ aren't we getting by Clifford's theorem that $h^0(\Delta+H) -1 \leq \frac{16}{2}=8$, i.e $h^0(\Delta+H)  \leq 9$ and hence $h^0(\Delta-H)  \geq 1$ ? Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: This is correct, but what do you do with that? For my argument I need $h^0(\Delta -H)\geq 2$.

Comment: can we say something if we know that $\Delta^2=8$?

Comment: What do you call $\Delta^2$?

Comment: by $\Delta^2$ I mean its self intersection number.

Comment: Self-intersection on a curve???

Comment: originally my $X$ was a smooth hyperplane section of a  surface and the divisor was on the surface. In that context self intersection number of the divisor came up. I didn't mention the surface earlier as I thought the intersection number related information might not be required to prove impossibility.